# Many-to-Many data modelling between fields for each record in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Lets say I have to save records of cloths in mongoDB. Attribute of the cloth is

- name
- description
- style

  - size
  - color
  - condition
- brand

  - brandName
  - someAttrubute
- price

For every cloth price changes for each combination of style and brand. So How do I model this in mongoDB.
So far what I have been thinking is:

```
{
  "name": "A name",
  "description": "A typical description",
  "style":[
    {"size": "XL","color": "red", "condition": "good"},//--style 0
    {"size": "XXL","color": "white", "condition": "bad"},//--style 1
    //...
    {"size": "L","color": "black", "condition": "best"}//--style N
  ],
  "brand":[
    {"brandName":"brand0","someAttribute":"Attribute 0"},
    {"brandName":"brand1","someAttribute":"Attribute 1"},
    {"brandName":"brand2","someAttribute":"Attribute 2"}
  ],
  "price":[
    //Every price need to be added for every combination of brand and style
    {"style":0,"brand":0,"price": 10},
    {"style":0,"brand":1,"price": 20},
    {"style":0,"brand":2,"price": 30},
    {"style":1,"brand":0,"price": 10},
    {"style":1,"brand":1,"price": 20},
    //...
    {"style":"N","brand":2,"price": 10}
  ]
}
```

I don't think this is the right way to do it in mongoDB. How to model this?

Comment: This is actually far too-broad a topic, and there generally is no such thing as *"the right way"* but only what is *"best for your application"*. One thing you should be aware of though is it is not possible to create an index that covers more than "one" array field. You can pair an array field in an index with other regular fields, but where multiple arrays are concerned this cannot be done. See ["limitations"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/#limitations) under the Multikey indexes manual page. So you generally will want something "flatter" than what your instincts think.

Answer (score 0):

I would go like this,

```
{
    "name": "A name",
    "description": "A typical description",
    "priceGroup" : [
        {
            "style": {"size": "XL","color": "red", "condition": "good"},
            "brand": {"brandName":"brand0","someAttribute":"Attribute 0"}
            "price": 10 
        },
        {
            "style": {"size": "XXL","color": "white", "condition": "bad"},
            "brand": {"brandName":"brand0","someAttribute":"Attribute 0"}
            "price": 20 
        },
        {
            "style": {"size": "XL","color": "red", "condition": "good"},
            "brand": {"brandName":"brand1","someAttribute":"Attribute 1"}
            "price": 30 
        },
        {
            "style": {"size": "XXL","color": "white", "condition": "bad"},
            "brand": {"brandName":"brand1","someAttribute":"Attribute 1"}
            "price": 40 
        },
        .....
    ]
}
```

But as @Neil Lunn pointed out, while designing nosql schemas, there are no rules as in relational database design concept - no normalization. Hence it is more up to your application and requirements. Put the things that you will be querying all together in a collection, and the others in a different collection.